# Vue-cli 5 publish a single js and load from html page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli-5

I'm develop an app in Vue 2, using webpack. Currently only publish a '.js' file in remote directory, and from a Sharepoint page will be loaded.
I'm trying to migrate to Vue 3, but I can't publish only de js file, and it will not loaded from Sharepoint page.

Here my old webpack config for vue 2

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: 'Q:\\js',
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: `appName.${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'prod' : 'jmp'}.js`,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
                        // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
                        // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
                        'scss': [
                            'vue-style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader'
                        ],
                        'sass': [
                            'vue-style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                        ]
                    },
                    // other vue-loader options go here
                    preserveWhitespace: false,
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true,
        overlay: true
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
    // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        })
    ])
}
```

a fragment from package.json for vue 2

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
},
```

and here my vue.config.js for vue 3

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
    outputDir: 'Q:\\js\\prova',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filenameHashing: false,
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    configureWebpack: config => {
        config.entry = './src/main.js';
        config.optimization.splitChunks = false;
        if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
            config.output.filename = 'prova-vue-3.[name].prod.js';
        } else {
            config.output.filename = 'prova-vue-3.[name].jmp.js';
        }

        config.module = {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader'
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.sass$/,
                    use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: {
                        loaders: {
                            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
                            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
                            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
                            'scss': [
                                'vue-style-loader',
                                'css-loader',
                                'sass-loader'
                            ],
                            'sass': [
                                'vue-style-loader',
                                'css-loader',
                                'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                            ]
                        },
                        // other vue-loader options go here
                        preserveWhitespace: false,
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                    }
                }
            ]
        };



        config.devServer = {
            historyApiFallback: true,
            noInfo: true,
            overlay: true
        };
        config.performance = {
            hints: false
        };
        config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';

    },
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.plugins.delete('html')
        config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
    }
})
```

and my package.json for vue 3

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development --watch",
    "serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development vue-cli-service serve"
},
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you publish the JS file? Maybe you should try `vue-custom-element` which will build your Vue application as a Web Component and you can then use this Web Component on any HTML page.

Comment: I can publish a JS file, but with more file, like html, I only want a unique JS. I will build like Web Component

Comment: Web Component is the optimal solution since you can include it several times on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found my error.
The deployment create 2 files, because in my router I was using lazy load for a component. It was a stupid error from my part.
Thanks to IVO GELOV for they comments